# Frequency-selective channel: Basic in theory

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, mimo

In a lecture, it was covered a topic "frequency selective and flat fading channel models".

For case, the frequency selective channel we have a channel impulse response `H` for each frequency,  is varying in frequency.

Last week I have a lab task where I have implemented the different precoding algorithms. Now I am thinking about how you calculate a precoding matrix for the frequency selective channel. You have more than one channel response, so you have to calculate for each of them. A calculation takes long. Of course, Matlab can do that very fast but you can have more than thousands response and it takes a long for Matlab too. How do you calculate in that case a precoding matrix? Do you take an average?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Noel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you need to recompute your precoding for every subcarrier.

In practice you might not want to do this as the computational complexity is pretty high. What one then typically does is grouping adjacent subcarriers and time indices together into "chunks" (I believe they are called resource blocks in LTE?) and just compute one precoding strategy for the entire chunk. The size of the chunk is a trade-off: if we make it too large, the quality of the precoding degrades because the channels becomes less and less similar over frequency and time. If we make it too small, computational complexity becomes an issue.

To determine the effective channel for the entire chunk that is used to compute the precoding, various strategies exist. The simplest might be just averaging the channels, for the MIMO case we often prefer to average the second-order statistics.

Comment: "grouping adjacent subcarriers", did you mean a grouping channel matrices?

Comment: Sure, in the MIMO case, the channels would be matrices. The point is to say that the channels in adjacent subcarriers are still somewhat similar so we can group them together.

Comment: As I remember the lecture about precoding techniques, If we add a precoding step, a performance of the channel will be bad. So if you group subcarriers, then the performance will be even worse, right?

Comment: Huh? I don't get your sentence: "if we add precoding, the performance will be bad"? Why would we do precoding? On the contrary, precoding should help you to improve the rate you can transfer over a channel...

Comment: one more question, I don't get one thing. You have written you prefer to average the second-order statistics. let assume 4 channel matrices and I group them: 1. with 2., 3. with 4. The next step is to average. If I take the average (mean), then I get a new  2 matrices. For the precoding strategy, I will use now these two new matrices. As I understood, I have  2 channel matrices, which I will multiply with Tx signal, decode, right?

Comment: I thought that precoding changes a preformance of the system

Comment: Could you suggest to me references where I can read more about it? I am not sure that it will be covered on out lecture/

Comment: You apply *pre*coding to the TX signal and *de*coding to the RX signal and you do both per-subcarrier (or per chunk of subcarriers / per resource block). This should enhance the performance of your system, that's why you're doing it. And yes, I also suggest you start with some more elementary book on the subject.  "Introduction to Space-Time Wireless Communications" by Paulraj and Nabar maybe? Or "MIMO Wireless Communications" by Goldsmith, Paulraj, Vince Poor and a couple others?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Comment: You're welcome! In case your question was answered please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Is there a case when performance increases with precoding?

Comment: As I said before: "precoding should help you to improve the rate you can transfer over a channel", so if you do it right, it should always work better with precoding. That's the reason you're doing it in the first place. If it doesn't improve you system, don't precode ^^

Comment: If I  recompute a precoding matrix for every subcarrier, I will compute svd for each `H` and take a product `V` with input vectors, correctly?  Maybe, it is stupid question for you ( sorry :( ), I am just trying to find an error in my simulation

Comment: Yes, SVD of each individual channel matrix. `V` for precoding, `U^H` for decoding.

Comment: To estimate data, I have made (`U^H*received_signal ./ diag( S)) `, where S is a diag matrix from SVD. Is it also correct? Should I use `pinv`  or  `./ S` ?

Comment: Sounds about right (the one with the diag), provided that S does not have zeros on its main diagonal. If it does, you need to truncate your SVD (and use fewer streams).

Comment: Is there method how I can check if  `V*data` is calculated correct?

Comment: Well, if your TX is `tx=V*data` and your RX is `rx=(U'*H*tx)./diag(S)`, then `rx` needs to be exactly equal to `data` (try without noise).

Comment: If i use `filter` ( `filter(H,tx)`)...can I get `rx` edual to `data`?

Comment: will be it work for OFDM?

Comment: I highly suggest you start with the frequency flat case. Once it works there you can go to OFDM. No need to use filter in the flat fading case.

Comment: I have found that the centre subcarrier provides the best performance in grouping schemes. How can it be explained?

Comment: Not sure I get your question exactly but I would say when you average a slowly varying process, among all its elements, the center one is closest to all of them and hence closest to the average. That's just because the space from the center to the edges is less allowing less room for decorrelation.

Comment: does the number of antennas effect for the size of a resource block? Can I conclude that with increasing the number of antennas, the size of the "possible" block is decreased?

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't know for sure, you would have to ask a channel modeling expert. My intuition would be that correlation in space and frequency are assumed separable so that the correlation in frequency would not be affected by increasing the number of antennas. But maybe more elaborate channel models exist that try to take the joint space-frequency correlation into account. I suggest to look out for recent publications in this area.